# How to run `nano` when using a `vim file` command

Tags: executable

I've been trying to find out how to change application executables (I don't know how to call them) so when you do `vim file` in the console it actually runs `nano file`.

I don't care if `vim` is installed or not on the operating system.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`. This works even after the installation of `vim`, because applications in `/usr/local/bin` have a higher priority per default PATH settings. To run the native `vim` installation you would have to run the full path `/usr/bin/vim`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nano /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Check the symbolic link with

```
stat /usr/local/bin/vim
```

You should see something like this:

```
  File: ‘/usr/local/bin/vim’ -> ‘/usr/bin/nano’
  Size: 11          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 5377195     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-11-29 20:22:49.266067541 +0100
Modify: 2015-11-29 20:22:47.566056452 +0100
Change: 2015-11-29 20:22:47.566056452 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Will this break when vim is upgraded?

Comment: Now it works also after the installation of vim

Comment: You've got a typo in the command: "loval" vs "local".

Answer (score 7):

You can use an alias, that way you don't have to move `vim` and the behavior is changed only at the shell's level:

```
printf 'alias vim=nano\n' >>~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This should either be `function vim { nano "$@"; }\n` (note the quotes around the arguments) or simply `alias vim=nano\n`.

Comment: (You need the quotes for the word-splitting to work properly; try `vim "file name"` in each case.)

Comment: @WChargin Not sure what I was thinking, I initially proposed an alias in fact (see the revision history) but switched to a function. Really, I don't know what I thought. Thanks, I also added the newline (which I forgot previously).